Can't reboot Ubuntu 24.04
I recently started using Linux and everything was going well until it crashed. Every time I start my laptop it shows the grub page with the list, Ubuntu, Advanced options, etc., so I tried choosing Ubuntu, but it doesn't reboot. The screen goes completely blank and stays that way.
Then I tried hitting some recovery files, but all those ends up in command prompts and nothing happens. I tried plugging in the bootable USB, but can't find my root directory in the GNU GRUB page. I get this DRDY error message after hitting the recovery files which has to do with issues with the hard disk, but I don't know how to resolve this now. Any idea what to do?
After running the recovery file it shows this.

I tried putting commands in grub page that I thought could help, but prohibited by secure boot policy shows up for those.

Did you try selecting "advanced options"? You can choose an older kernel from the list, that might work.
Also, it would help sharing how it crashed - while opening an app, upgrading the system, etc, etc. Also, share your ubuntu version, how you installed it & how long was it running fine (since you mentioned you recently started).
